# wp_editor textarea value not updating

Tags: wp-editor

I am using the `*_add_form_fields` action to add fields to a custom taxonomy. One of those fields is a wp_editor().

The problem I am facing is that when I output the WordPress editor on the page like so:

```
wp_editor('test', 'mydescription', array('textarea_name' => 'my_description'));
```

and then if I click in the editor on the page and change the default value from `test` to `something else` the `$_POST['my_description']` variable is still set to `test`

Should I be adding an additional setting to my editor? Is there a reason why I cannot change the value of the textarea?

**EDIT**

Below is a very simple test case that shows this happening. Place this in your functions.php file and then create a new **tag**. The posted value for 'my_description" will not change.

```
class Test{

    function __construct() {

        add_action('add_tag_form_fields', array($this, 'add_tag_form_fields'));

        add_action('created_term', array($this, 'created_term'));
    }

    function add_tag_form_fields($tag){

        if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ): ?>

        <div class="form-field">
            <?php wp_editor('test', 'mydescription', array('textarea_name' => 'my_description')); ?>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

    function created_term($tag){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
            die();
    }
}
new Test();
```

**EDIT**

This ONLY happens when attaching to "created_term" action. If you attach to "edited_terms" it works as expected and I think this is a result of ajax being used on the create term page... I have updated the test code to show this.

Comment: It did change for me: `Array
(
    [action] => add-tag
    [screen] => edit-post_tag
    [taxonomy] => post_tag
    [post_type] => post
    [_wpnonce_add-tag] => 4f7d3df228
    [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag
    [tag-name] => Test99
    [slug] => 
    [description] => 
    [my_description] => something else
)`, maybe something else in your code a problem?

Comment: see second edit. It appears that this only happens when you "add" a term.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*tinyMCE* `<textarea>` element is initially unseen by the used serialize function:

```
$.post(
    ajaxurl,
    $('#addtag').serialize(), function(r) {
        // Content here.
    }
});
```

You will need to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` to make it visible.

Below is a simple snippet that should do the trick:

```
jQuery('#submit').mousedown( function() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

This in an external file, enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script()`; it worked for the test I've conducted.

Comment: This does not work for me. It appears the data is posted, THEN your click function code is triggered.

Comment: did you enqueued the script in the head? if you enqueue it in the footer, it will be loaded after wp-scripts and that'd be too late.

Comment: instead of 'click' you actually could bind it to $('#submit').mousedown( ... ) :)

in that case it shouldn't matter where and when the script is loaded.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your `edited_terms` function you need to save the value and in your `add_tag_form_fields`
you need replace your `test` with the saved data.

something like:

```
class Test{

    function __construct() {

        //do_action('add_tag_form_fields', $taxonomy);
        add_action('add_tag_form_fields', array($this, 'add_tag_form_fields'));

        //do_action("edited_terms", $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy);
        add_action('edited_terms', array($this, 'edited_terms'));
    }

    function add_tag_form_fields($term){

        if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ): ?>

        <div class="form-field">
            <?php 
            $saved = get_option('termmeta_'.$term->term_id);
            $saved = (empty($saved))? 'test': $saved;
            wp_editor($saved, 'mydescription', array('textarea_name' => 'my_description')); ?>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

    function edited_terms($term_id){
        if (isset($_POST['mydescription'])){
            update_option('termmeta_'.$term_id,$_POST['mydescription']);
        }
    }
}
new Test();
```

Now if you want a much easier way of adding extra fields of all types to your tags/categories or custom taxonomy edit forms without reinventing the wheel take a look at [**`TAX Meta Class`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way)

Comment: See my second comment, it appears that this only happens when adding a term. And I think this is a result of it using ajax.

Comment: @Mike what Ajax where are you using Ajax?

Comment: When you add a new category/term WordPress uses ajax to post the data and create the new term. For some reason this does not allow the wp_editor element to have the correct value. Try the test code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the codex for [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) the first argument should be the content. So rather than 'test' you should put `$_POST['my_description']` if that is what you would like the initial content to be.

Comment: the issue is not with the content showing up correctly. It is with the posted variable being the same as the original content even if you change the textarea content to something else.