# wp_editor saving to database, but not displaying content on refresh

Tags: wp-editor

I'm looking to add a wp_editor() input to my WordPress plugin settings page.  I've followed the codex instructions and have run across a problem.

When I comment out the wp_editor line below, the textarea saves content properly and auto-populates the field on page reload.

But, when I comment out the $html = '' line, the wp_editor saves content properly, but DOES NOT auto-populate the field on page reload.

```
$output = $args[0].'[content]';
    $value  = isset( $args[1]['content'] ) ? $args[1]['content'] : '';
    $id = $args[0].'_content';
    $settings = array( 
        'textarea_name' => $output, 
        'textarea_rows' => '5'
    );  
    wp_editor( $value, $id, $settings );

    $html = '<textarea id="' .$output. '" name="' .$output. '" rows="6" style="width: 90%; padding: 10px;" type="textarea">' .$value. '</textarea>';

    $html .= '<p class="description">' . __( 'Enter default content to be displayed within the WYSIWYG editor, such as "delete this, then start writing". HTML and shortcodes allowed.', $this->plugin_slug ) . '</p><br />';

    echo $html;
```

My question is, what is happening here?  Does the wp_editor() need something extra from me so it can recognize content associated with it and populate the editor when the page loads?

Even if I set $value = 'Hello World!'; I get the same result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think you need to create a <textarea> with wp_editor. Just call it, making sure it gets the correct id and name args handed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for here - [wp_editor textarea value not updating](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39594/wp-editor-textarea-value-not-updating?rq=1)

Better late than never!